# html pages auto cicling using js script

Tags: javascript, html, refresh

I've a servlet that prints html pages. I would like that those pages auto cicling using a js script. So I load an html page, after 3 second it refresh and I load another html page (printed by the same servlet).

In the servlet:
- read the session where I store the index of the page i'm printing;
- basing on this index, I print the page and I update the index (it increase or it return to 0 if I'm printing last page)
- store the index in a div element, so I can find it by javascript function and refresh the html page with a js function

```
    out.println("<div id=\"storedDiv\">");
    int indexRefresh= (int) request.getSession().getAttribute("indexRefresh");
    out.println(Integer.toString(indexRefresh) );
    indexRefresh=indexRefresh+1;
    if (indexRefresh==Tot) {
        indexRefresh=0;
    }
    request.getSession().setAttribute("indexRefresh", indexRefresh);
    out.println("</div>");
```

The js function find the div element in the html page and update the page

```
function refresh(){
    var element = document.getElementById("storeDiv");
    if (element==0){
    setTimeout(function() {
          window.location.href = "http://localhost:9080/HydroGui/Query?anno=2018&id=1";
        }, 3000);   
    }
    if (element==1){
        setTimeout(function() {
              window.location.href = "http://localhost:9080/HydroGui/Query?anno=2018&id=2";
            }, 3000);   
        }
}
```

But where have I call the function? if I use the

```
window.onload = refresh();
```

page load before I stored the index in the div.
So what is the best method to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `innerHTML`

```
var element = document.getElementById("storeDiv").innerHTML;
if (element == '0') {
    //...
}
```

Comment: i cannot see the div element until page is load.

Comment: @Hydronit, you can see div element if script included after div and just call  `refresh` function